# Android: How to make a touch on a button inside a "for-loop" to make app start next round of the loop

Tags: android, for-loop, buttonclick

I am trying to find out the syntax on how to make a for-loop to wait for a buttonclick before the loop proceeds to the next round. The app might seem meaningless, but the point is to find out this syntax.

In the code beneath buttonA is supposed to change number for each round. The text in buttonA should be the current number in the counter (x) of the for-loop. I want it to display "1" at first, and when one of the buttons are clicked I want it to display "2" (because the next round in the for-loop x should be "2"), and next time "3". Using the code beneath buttonA displays "3" as the app start, so it´s obvious that the for-loop has finished before the app starts.

Here is the code in the onCreate-method:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView1;
private Button buttonA;
private Button buttonB;
private Button buttonC;
private TextView textView2;
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
    final Random rndNumber = new Random();

    for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++){
        buttonA.setText(Integer.toString(x));
        buttonB.setText("5");
        buttonC.setText("9");

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setText("Good, you pushed the right button");
            }
        });//End onClickListenerA
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setText("Wrong button");
            }
        });//End onClickListenerB
        buttonC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setText("Wrong button ");
            }
        });//End onClickListenerA
    }//End for-loop
}//End onCreate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um. Don't.

You want a loop like that you certainly can't do it threaded like that. You need to set the variables in the activity, wait for the user interaction, then increment the variable you have set and call a function to set up the next round.

```
int x;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
    final Random rndNumber = new Random();
    x = 1;
    setupRound();
}
private void setupRound() {
        buttonA.setText(Integer.toString(x));
        buttonB.setText("5");
        buttonC.setText("9");

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setText("Good, you pushed the right button");
                 setupRound();
            }
        });//End onClickListenerA
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setText("Wrong button");
                setupRound();
            }
        });//End onClickListenerB
        buttonC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setText("Wrong button ");
                setupRound();
            }
        });//End onClickListenerA
i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But what if I want the program to stop after x <= 5? How would I manage to stop it without using a for-loop or a while-loop?

Comment: Make an exit condition. "if (x > 5) return;" in the setup round. Or rather set the rest of the stuff invisible or whatever you want when you exit.

Comment: This worked when I put the statement ( if (x > 5) {return;} ) inside the buttonA-onClick-method. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a for-loop in your case.

Try to just use a counter:

```
private int mCounterX;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
    final Random rndNumber = new Random();
    mCounterX= 1;
    buttonA.setText(Integer.toString(mCounterX));
    buttonB.setText("5");
    buttonC.setText("9");

    buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             textView2.setText("Good, you pushed the right button");
             mCounterX++;
             buttonA.setText(Integer.toString(mCounterX));
         }
    });//End onClickListenerA

    buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             textView2.setText("Wrong button");
             mCounterX++;
             buttonA.setText(Integer.toString(mCounterX));
         }
    });//End onClickListenerB

    buttonC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             textView2.setText("Wrong button ");
             mCounterX++;
             buttonA.setText(Integer.toString(mCounterX));
         }
     });//End onClickListenerA

}//End onCreate
```